# Test Class Error on Trigger UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION

Tags: unit-test

so I'm getting this error below. Seems like its pretty explanatory right? The thing is that I have another class that actually inserts the user, and the test class on that works fine. All this trigger is doing is inserting a contact that matches the info of the Case. I've included my test class & trigger below, I figured this would be an easy fix for someone that knows more about this than me, maybe my eyes are just failing me!

```
 trigger CreateContactonCase on Case (before insert, before update) {
if(Trigger.isInsert){

List<Contact> ct = new List <Contact>();

for(Case acc : trigger.new){

    Contact c = new Contact
                (LastName = acc.Contact_Last_Name__c,
                Account=acc.Account,
                FirstName = acc.Contact_First_Name__c,
                //AccountId=acc.id,
                //Account= acc.Account_Name_If_not_in_Salesforce__c,
                MailingStreet=acc.Account_Address__c,
                /* MailingCity=acc.BillingCity,
               /* MailingState=acc.BillingState,
                MailingPostalCode=acc.BillingPostalCode,
                MailingCountry=acc.BillingCountry,*/
                //Name=acc.Contact,
                Role__c=acc.Contact_Role__c,
                Title=acc.Title__c,
                Phone=acc.Contact_Phone__c,
                CIS_Contact__c= false,
                Contact_Not_Verified_del__c = false,
               // ManageExternalUser  = true, 
                Email=acc.Contact_Email__c);
                //update c;


    ct.add(c);
    acc.Status ='Closed';
    acc.Portal_User_Created__c = true;
    //acc.Completed_By__c = System.user;
    acc.Completed_Date__c = System.today();
}

insert ct;
update ct;


}
```

}

```
 @IsTest
public class CreateContactonCase_TST {

static testmethod void CreateContactonCase () {
  Account a = new account (name ='testaccount');
  insert a;
  Case acc = new Case
                (Contact_Last_Name__c = 'TestLastname',
                Account= [SELECT id, name FROM Account WHERE name = 'test account'],
                Contact_First_Name__c = 'TestFirstName',
                //AccountId=acc.id,
                //Account= acc.Account_Name_If_not_in_Salesforce__c,
                Account_Address__c='TestAddress',
                /* MailingCity=acc.BillingCity,
               /* MailingState=acc.BillingState,
                MailingPostalCode=acc.BillingPostalCode,
                MailingCountry=acc.BillingCountry,*/
                //Name=acc.Contact,
                Contact_Role__c='TestRole',
                Title__c='TestTitle',
                Contact_Phone__c='12345678',
                //CIS_Contact__c= false,
                //Contact_Not_Verified_del__c = false,
               // ManageExternalUser  = true, 
                Contact_Email__c='testemail@email.com');
                insert acc;


}
List<Contact> c = new List <Contact>();
List<Case> cs = new List <Case>();
```

ERROR MSG

System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, portal account owner must have a role: []

**ADDED**

thanks for the reply!!

So I went ahead and made some editions to both the trigger and the method where the error was reporting from. And now i'm getting this error. Basically I added to my Test Class:

```
UserRole portalRole = [Select Id From UserRole Where PortalType = 'None' Limit 1];

User portalAccountOwner1 = new User(

UserRoleId = portalRole.Id,

ProfileId = profile1.Id,

Username = System.now().millisecond() + 'test3@test.com',

Alias = 'batman',

Email='bruce.wayne@wayneenterprises.com',

EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',

Firstname='Bruce',

Lastname='Wayne',

LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',

LocaleSidKey='en_US',

TimeZoneSidKey='America/Chicago'
```

);

This was to insert a user so I could use the system run as method

Next I put this in my actual method:

```
 @future public static void createUser(Id ContactId, string UserRoleId, String email, String firstName, String lastName, String userName, String profileId, boolean IsPortalEnabled) {
    Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
    dmo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = true;
    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Partner Community User Custom'];
    **UserRole portalRole = [Select Id From UserRole Where PortalType = 'None' Limit 1];**
    User u = new User(alias = 'standt', email=email, CommunityNickname =lastname,
        emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname=lastname, languagelocalekey='en_US', 
        localesidkey='en_US', profileid = p.Id , contactId=contactId, **UserRoleId=PortalRole.Id**, 
        timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', //IsPortalEnabled = false,
        username=email);

    u.setOptions(dmo);
    insert u;
```

(I only added the SOQL statement and the UserRoleId = PortalRole.Id)

I thought this would be sufficient, but I am now getting this error: **System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, High Volume Portal Users cannot have a user role: [UserRoleId]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means what it says: a portal account (that is, an account with a contact that is enabled as a portal user) must be owned by a user that has a role.   I don't immediately see why you are getting this error; it's also not clear which insert is throwing the error; it's probably the contact insert in the trigger, but checking the error line number in the log is probably a good idea.

**aside:** Where I usually see this error is when setting up a community user for the first time in a DE org; for whatever reason the DE org default (sysadmin) user doesn't get a Role assigned automatically, and that user owns all the demo accounts & contacts.  Create a community, pick an existing contact, choose Manage External User->Enable Customer User, and you'll see the error.  I'm not sure if there's another trigger in the org that's getting involved once the contact is inserted or what; again, check the log and pin down the code line throwing the error.

One other thing I noticed, in your test method, your account names don't match: `Account a = new account (name ='testaccount');` but `Account= [SELECT id, name FROM Account WHERE name = 'test account']` ("testaccount" != "test account").  If you have @SeeAllData=true in your test class you may be getting a different account than the one you expect.

One other general comment.  I don't know what your case create flow is like, this may not be an issue for you; but you should probably check that Case.ContactID == null (that is, there's not already a contact on the case) before creating a new contact.

**Update**: in your new createUser method you have these two lines:

```
Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Partner Community User Custom'];
UserRole portalRole = [Select Id From UserRole Where PortalType = 'None' Limit 1];
```

You then create a user with this profile and role.  As the error message points states, "High Volume Portal Users cannot have a user role".  In other words, remove the portalRole from the `new User` statement, you don't need it.  Going back to my original answer, the user that needs a role is the Internal User who owns the Account to which the Contact belongs.

Comment: thanks for the reply!!

So I went ahead and made some editions to both the trigger and the method where the error was reporting from. And now i'm getting this error. Basically I added to my Test Class:

   

(I only added the SOQL statement and the UserRoleId = PortalRole.Id)

I thought this would be sufficient, but I am now getting this error: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, High Volume Portal Users cannot have a user role: [UserRoleId]

Comment: Plz see code above, I cannot post updated code in comments because character limits : )

Comment: So in that case, could I just theorhetically set the OwnerId field of the account that im inserting in the test class to this role?

Answer (score 1):

The user that is trying to create the portal user needs a role. In this case it is a script that is trying to create that user and that script runs with your permissions, so YOUR OWN PROFILE needs to have a role.

I ran into this a few times.

This is the utility method I use to create a test portal user:

```
public static User portalUserWithProfile(String profileName, String accountName, String contactName) {

    Contact c = NewContact(NewAccount(accountName), contactName);

    Profile p = [select id from profile where name = :profileName];

    User u = new User(Alias='ptest', email='portaltestuser@testorg.com',
        emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname=contactName, languagelocalekey='en_US',
        localesidkey='en_US', profileid = p.Id,
        timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', username='portaltestuser@testorg.com',
         ContactId = c.Id, IsActive=true);
    insert u;

    c.User_Account__c = u.Id;
    update c;

    return u;
}
```